# Disproving that if $x^2_n$ is Cauchy, then $x_n$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

I tried to work backwards from the fact that $x^2_n$ is cauchy to find a case where $x_n$ is not cauchy.

$\vert x^2_n-x^2_m \vert \lt \epsilon$

$\vert (x_n-x_m)(x_n+x_m) \vert \lt \epsilon$

$\vert x_n-x_m \vert \vert x_n+x_m \vert \geq \vert (x_n-x_m)(x_n+x_m) \vert \lt \epsilon$    (proved earlier in class)

Then a case would exist that $\vert x_n-x_m \vert \gt \epsilon/(\vert x_n+x_m\vert)$, making $x_n$ not a Cauchy sequence since $\epsilon/(\vert x_n+x_m \vert)\gt0$

Is this a legitimate approach, or are there assumptions that aren't allowed? Just looking for feedback as this is for a graded assignment that I can only seek guidance, not solutions for.

Comment: Are you assuming $x_n \ge 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: @Henry I am not, I reasoned that because of the absolute value it would be irrelevant if $x_n \lt 0$

Comment: Your third line looks strange to me. If $|(x_n-x_m)(x_n+x_m)|\lt \varepsilon$, then $|x_n-x_m| \lt \dfrac{\varepsilon}{|x_n+x_m|}$

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have variable pairing with $\epsilon$.

A counterexample is the sequence defined by $(1,-1,1,-1,...)$, the absolute value is the constant sequence.

Comment: I see. So would my solution need to somehow deduce that some $\epsilon$ not dependent on a variable is less than $\vert x_n-x_m \vert$ or should I not be starting with the fact that $x^2_n$ is Cauchy?

Comment: The philosophy of $\epsilon$-argument is that, the final step of $\epsilon$ inequality cannot end up with variable pairing with it, this is very crucial.

Comment: Would it be the same process as proving that a sequence is Cauchy, just instead of $ \lt \epsilon$, I find that it is $ \gt \epsilon$? I'm not familiar with showing that sequences aren't Cauchy as I've almost exclusively dealt with showing that sequences are Cauchy.

Comment: If you end up something with $>\epsilon$, then it is not Cauchy, but usually this is not a very easy way, usually we select a concrete $\epsilon$ as a number and show that $>(\text{a number})$ and then conclude that it is not Cauchy.